# P-LSTM conceptual questions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, batch-normalization

Phased-LSTM was published [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09513) I use it with my models and in my case it shows a satisfying improvement over batch normalized LSTM models.
I'm looking for explanation on the following questions:

- Is PLSTM conceptually conflicting with [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf)? I tried to implement using Keras and Tensorflow but batchnorm seems to interfere with the time gate and results are significantly worse than plain PLSTM. I don't understand the reason.
- Can I stack PLSTM layers like it is commonly done with LSTM? My understanding is that in this case the first layer's time gate will "hide" information from the second layer therefore adding a second layer doesn't make sense. Also I tried and this seems to be the case because 3 stacked PLSTM layers produce almost exact same results as a single layer.